# Is Ganesh true dev?

Tags: ganesha, gods, brihadaranyaka-upanishad

I read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-three_gods) article on wikipedia which is about thirty three devatas (trayastrimsati koti). But there is no Ganesha in them.

I would like to ask in which category Ganesha Belong?

Comment: There is no necessity that ALL Gods are to be included among these 33 kinds of Deities.For example Lord Brahma is not included in the list.Lord Ganesha is one of the 5 MOST important Deities in hinduism and probably the most worshipped.

Comment: @Rickross It means there are more than 33 devtas?. And this number may be till 33 crores?

Comment: 33 types of deities are there.Not 33 crores, thats absurd.But that does not imply that the list of 33 such dieties covers all the devatas .As u can see from Lord Brahma's example.He is not covered.

Comment: @Rickross Can we count total?

Answer (score 3):

Mahabharata accepts Lord Ganesha as a true Devata. After all it was Lord Ganesha who actually wrote the Itihasa (although this is not accepted by the Bhandarkar critical edition). I am also posting this additional passage that reinforces Lord Ganesha's claim to be a true Deva.

**Narada on 5 deities**

> Narada said, ‘Thou art He who is the topic of the five foremost of
> scriptures (viz., those that appertain to the worship of Surya, of
> Sakti, of **Ganesa**, of Siva, and of Vishnu).

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCXXXIX**

In addition to the above the first possible references are in Krsna Yajur Veda.

> In the Maitrayaniya Samhita of the Krsna Yajur Veda we come across the
> first stray references which leave footprints eerily suggesting
> (pertaining to?) an elephant. For instance, we find the words ***karata***
> (one having the cheek of an elephant; one having a trunk), ***hastimukha***
> (one having the face and head of an elephant), and ***dantin*** (one having
> a tusk). In the same Krsna Yajur Veda, in its Tattiriya Aranyaka we
> find the words ***vakratunda*** ( one with a twisted trunk) and ***dantin*** (one
> having a tusk).
>
> *tat karataya vidmaye, **hastimukhaya** dhimahi, tan no danti pracodayat*
>
> [May we know that grotesque one; may we meditate on the one with the
> elephant face; may that one-toothed one inspire this our knowledge and
> meditation.]
>
> *tat purusaya vidmahe, **vakratundaya** dhimahi, tan no **danti** pracodayat*
>
> [May we know that divine one; may we meditate on the one with the
> curved trunk; may that one-toothed one inspire that knowledge and
> meditation of ours.]
>
> Both these texts from the Krsna Yajur Veda mention a gayatri addressed
> to a deity called "***dantin***" (the tasked one). One would expect such a
> reference suggestive of Ganesa, and the famous Vedic commentator
> Sayana explicitly establishes this identification in his commentary on
> the Taittiriya Aranyaka.
>
> In the Narayana Upanishad, Ganapati is addressed as the god who
> possesses a twisted trunk (***vakratunda***).

**Ganapati Song of the Self, Chapter 2, In the Beginning ..., by John Grimes**

Comment: What if if Sri Ganesha was not accepted(as a true Deva) in Mahabharatha??He would not have been "true Deva" then?

Comment: It helps that Mahabharata accepts Ganesha as a true Deva. That means that Ganesha had wide acceptance among Hindus thousands of years ago. That's all I am saying. I will not speculate on what would have happened if Mahabharata did not accept Ganesha as a true Deva.

Comment: "Although this is not accepted by the Bhandarkar critical edition" - Interesting, why didn't BORI accept it?

Comment: Bibek DebRoy's recent translation of Mahabharata makes this claim. It doesn't say why. The critical edition has only about 77,000 verses compared to nearly 95,000 verses in some non-critical manuscripts.

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to vote a lot here?  FYI: [How to increase Voting contribution in Hinduism.SE?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/659/2995)

Comment: I have voted 128 times. Isn't that a lot?

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay FYI, since you forgot to use `@sv.` I didn't get the last two comment notifications. You can see top voters [at this link](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). Since we have about 4000 Q's and 5000 A's .. 128 votes is not a lot :) So encourage you to vote more, both Q's and A's. As you can see top voter has voted 3500+ times!

Comment: @sv I will try to improve :)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes , Shree Ganesh is true Deva or God** and not only that **he is said to be the the Brahman** ,giving Consciousness to All. We can find his description   In [**Ganapati Atharvashirsha (Ganapati Upanishad)**](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-ganapati_atharvashirsha.php)
Here he is said to be the  visible Brahman -:

> त्वं **प्रत्यक्षं ब्रह्मासि** - । Tvam P**ratyakssam Brahma-Asi**
>
> **You are the visible Brahman** (manifested as the Universe) (Therefore, O
>   Ganapati, the Absolute Truth I have spoken will make the realized see
>   this vast World as emanating from Sacchidananda)
>
> त्वमेव सर्वं खल्विदं **ब्रह्मासि** - ।Tvam-Eva Sarvam Khalv[u]-Idam
>   **Brahma-Asi** |
>
> (O Ganapati) You indeed are All This (The Universe); You verily are
>   the Brahman (giving Consciousness to All)

Here he is said to be INDRA ,AGNI ,SURYA ,CHANDRA ,WIND etc.

> > मिन्द्रस्त्वम  स्त्वमग्निस्त्वं वायुस्त्वं सूर्यस्त्वं चन्द्रमास्त्वं ब्रह्म भूर्भुवस्सुवरोम् ॥६॥
> >  Vaayus-Tvam Suuryas-Tvam
> >     Candramaas-Tvam Brahma Bhuur-Bhuvas-Suvar-Om 
> >  Meaning: You are
> >     Indra, You are Agni (God of Fire), You are ... Vayu (God of Wind), You
> >     are Surya (The Sun God), You are Chandrama (The Moon God), You are ...
> >     Brahman (Absolute Consciousness), You pervade the Bhur-Bhuvah-Suvar
> >     Lokas; **You are the Om Itself** (Parabrahman).

Here in the end we can  find  Rushi Gannaka calling him as a God.

> सैषा गणेशविद्या । गणक ऋषिः । निचृद्गायत्रीच्छन्दः ।
>   **गणपतिर्देवता ।** ॐ गं गणपतये नमः ॥९॥
>
> Sai[a-E]ssaa Gannesha-Vidyaa | Gannaka Rssih | Nicrdgaayatriic-Chandah
>   |
>   **Gannapatir-Devataa** | Om Gam Gannapataye Namah
>
> This is the Ganesha Vidya (A path leading to the Knowledge of the Self
>   through the worship of Ganesha through His Mantra Swarupa), The Rishi
>   who realized this Vidya is Ganaka Rishi, The Chhanda (Metre) is
>   Nicrdgayatri,
>   **The Devata (God) worshipped is Ganapati,** Om Gang Ganapataye Namah (My Reverential Salutations to Ganapati), I seek Your Blessings to
>   practice this Vidya)

He is the son of Lord Shiva and Parvati. A interested story of his birth is also  given in **Vaman Purana. (Chapter 54 –Birth Of Ganesa)**. Although he is not mentioned in the list given by you in your answer. **He is most popularly worshiped as a God worldwide.**
in which category Ganesha Belong -: (Adi-Dev , Lord of Ganas,Para-Brahman)

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ganapati or Ganesha is a Vedic God.

Here is [Vedic](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-gananam_tva_ganapatim.php) verse dedicated to him which is widely used as an Avahana Mantra for Lord Ganapati.:

> ॐ गणानां त्वा गणपतिं हवामहे कविं कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम् । ज्येष्ठराजं
>   ब्रह्मणाम् ब्रह्मणस्पत आ नः शृण्वन्नूतिभिःसीदसादनम् ॥ ॐ महागणाधिपतये
>   नमः ॥
>
> Om Gannaanaam Tvaa Ganna-Patim Hava-Amahe Kavim
>   Kaviinaam-Upama-Shravas-Tamam | Jyessttha-Raajam Brahmannaam
>   Brahmannas-Pata Aa Nah Shrnnvan-Nuutibhih-Siida-Saadanam || Om
>   Mahaa-Ganna-Adhipataye Namah ||

**Meaning**

> 1: Om, O Ganapati, To You Who are the Lord of the Ganas (Celestial
>   Attendants or Followers), we Offer our Sacrificial Oblations, 2: You
>   are the Wisdom of the Wise and the Uppermost in Glory, 3: You are the
>   Eldest Lord (i.e. ever Unborn) and is of the Nature of Brahman
>   (Absolute Consciousness); You are the Embodiment of the Sacred Pranava
>   (Om), 4: Please come to us by Listening to our Prayers and be Present
>   in the Seat of this Sacred Sacrificial Altar. 5: Om, our Prostrations
>   to the Mahaganadhipati (the Great Lord of the Ganas).

Similar verse is in Yajurveda too:

> **Ganaanaam tvaa ganapatim** havaamahé Priyaanaam tvaa Priyapatim
>   havaamahé, Nidheenaam tvaa nidhipatim havaamahe. vaso mama.
>   Aahamajaani garbhadhamaa tvamajaasi garbhadham.  (Yajurveda: 23. 19)

Now,some people have confusion whether Brahmanaspati refered along with Ganapati in these verses is at all Lord Ganesha or Deva Guru Brihaspati.

Here is what i think:

These verses find place in the famous Vedic Suktam called the [Ganapati Suktam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlPuPepLo0o) .And these verses are widely used in all Vedic Pujas as avahana mantras for Ganesha.So,i can't believe that they will wrongly use mantras that are related to Brihaspati during Puja of Lord Ganapati.

Also from [this](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/ganapati-brahmanaspati-and-kumara-mantras-from-rig-veda-yajur-veda-and-upanishdas-sanskrit-text-with-transliteration-and-english-translation-NAE891/) page we find:

> The word Ganapati accompanies the word Brahmanaspati in several
>   mantras.**The great Tantric and commentator in Veda ,Kapali Sastry
>   declares that the deity Ganapati and Brahmanaspati are the same.**
>
> [image]

Image courtesy-Extoticindiaart.com.

Ganapati is also one of the [Pancha Devatas](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pancha_devatha_Sthuthi) or the 5 (principle) Deities in Hinduism the other 4 being Shiva,Vishnu,Devi and Surya.So,he belongs to the category of Pancha Devatas.

In every Hindu ceremonies worshiping the Pancha Devatas is usually  recommended.

> [image]
>
> Adityam GananAtham Cha Devim Rudram Cha Keshavam |
>   PanchaDaivatyamityuktam Sarva Karmasu PujAyeth ||
>
> Meaning-The Pancha Devas are -Surya,Ganesha,Devi,Shiva and Vishnu.In
>   all ceremonies they should be worshiped.**(Matsya Purana)**

Comment: -1 Gnanan tva refers to brihaspati check rigveda anukramanika.

Comment: @TheDestroyer See the revised answer..